# Change Activation (Tab Focus) Behavior for Vimperator Mappings

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I want to create a new vimperator key mapping that duplicates the functionality of undo, but opens the tab in an unfocused/background tab.

I know that tabopen uses the flag ! to toggle activation behavior for the new tab, but the command :u! does not work in the same way. Is there any way to do this without resorting to javascript (which I don't know)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to your `.vimperatorrc` file to create a command `undob` which reopens closed tabs in the background, preserving their history and not affecting the current alternate tab.

```
command! undob -description "Undo closed tab in background" :js undob();
:js <<EOF
  undob = function() {
      var currT = gBrowser.selectedTab;
      var ssService = Components.interfaces.nsISessionStore;
      var ssClass = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/browser/sessionstore;1']
      var ss = ssClass.getService(ssService);
      var closedTabs = JSON.parse(ss.getClosedTabData(window));
      var ct0 = closedTabs[0]
      ss.undoCloseTab(window, ct0);
      gBrowser.selectedTab = currT;
  }
EOF
```

Example key binding <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>:

```
nnoremap <C-c>u :undob<CR>
```

Comment: It looks like this still switches focus to the newly opened tab. I'd like to keep the focus on the current tab and "undo" the closed tab without switching to it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I got confused and just replicated normal `:undo`. Actually, I can't think of a way to do this offhand. Vimperator doesn't seem to have the `:background` command, and even on Pentadactyl, it doesn't seem to work with `:undo`. You might need a custom javascript function. I'll look into it later and get back to you.

Comment: @ccqmp: Okay, I've got this working. Let me know if there are any issues.